# Can I approve my own suggested edit once I reach 2k reputation?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

Suppose I have 1998 reputation points and suggest an edit. Then, I get upvoted and have now 2003 or 2008 reputation points. If I run to review suggested edits, can I review my own edit? Do I gain any reputation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot review your own suggested edits to approve them. There are measures in place that prevent that scenario, since up until 20,000 reputation, your edits on tag wikis and their excerpts would still require approval from others (and obviously during that time you'd have access to the Suggested Edits queue).

Comment: I was kind of hoping you wouldn't've thought of this yet...